# Xamarin Android Layout issue

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a simple Xamarin layout that doesn't render correctly.  There are extra columns on the rows (4,5,6) that only contain a single UI element.  Here is the XML.  Based on other SO posts, setting the `layout_span=2` should fix the issue.  However it doesn't seem to work.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
    <TableRow
        p1:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:gravity="center_horizontal"
        p1:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            p1:text="Image Path"
            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            p1:id="@+id/pathLabel" />
        <EditText
            p1:inputType="text"
            p1:id="@+id/imagePathText"
            p1:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        p1:id="@+id/tableRow5">
        <TextView
            p1:text="Server Path"
            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            p1:id="@+id/textView10"
            p1:layout_column="0" />
        <EditText
            p1:id="@+id/serverPathText"
            p1:layout_column="1"
            p1:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        p1:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:gravity="center_horizontal"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            p1:text="Start Date"
            p1:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            p1:id="@+id/dateLabel" />
        <EditText
            p1:inputType="date"
            p1:id="@+id/dateText"
            p1:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        p1:id="@+id/tableRow6">
        <Button
            p1:text="Save"
            p1:id="@+id/saveButton"
            p1:layout_column="0"
            p1:layout_weight="1"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_span="2" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        p1:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_weight="100">
        <TextView
            p1:text="Text"
            p1:id="@+id/logView"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_height="match_parent"
            p1:layout_weight="1"
            p1:layout_span="2" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        p1:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            p1:layout_column="0"
            p1:id="@+id/syncButton"
            p1:text="@string/sync"
            p1:layout_width="match_parent"
            p1:layout_weight="1"
            p1:layout_span="2" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your code, it's correct.

**Try to close/open IDE, delete application from device and re-build project.**

[image]

Comment: Surprisingly, that worked.  I did a "Clean Solution" then a "Build Solution".   What a rookie mistake.  Thanks.